# Adjoint of an adjoint of an operator not the operator itself

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In sadri hassani book, the author claims that $(A^\dagger)^\dagger = A$ is only valid in finite dimensional spaces. To me this seems also true in infinite dimensions as can be proven from the definition that $\langle x|A|y\rangle^* = \langle y|A^\dagger|x\rangle$ for all $x$ and $y.$ This can be seen by taking the complex conjugate of both sides. The only way this can be false is if the complex conjugate of a complex number is not the number itself in infinite dimensions. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing that the domain is important. While what you said is true if the operator is defined everywhere, it needs no longer to be true for densely defined operators.

Comment: To expand on @SevereinSchraven's observation, your calculation$$\langle x|(A^\dagger)^\dagger|y\rangle=\langle y|A^\dagger|x\rangle^\ast=\langle x|A|y\rangle$$ is valid *if* $x,\,y$ are such that all three expressions are defined, so is true in general if the "legal" $x,\,y$ pairs are the same in all three cases.

Comment: The second adjoint actually doesn't even have to make sense: there are densely defined operators with not densely defined adjoints.

Answer (score 1):

The following extends a little bit of your concern:

For normed spaces $X,Y$ and a bounded operator $A:X\rightarrow Y$, we defined $A^{\ast}:Y^{\ast}\rightarrow X^{\ast}$ by $\left<x,Ay^{\ast}\right>=\left<Ax,y^{\ast}\right>$ and we can further define $A^{\ast\ast}:X^{\ast\ast}\rightarrow Y^{\ast\ast}$ by $\left<y^{\ast},A^{\ast\ast}x^{\ast\ast}\right>=\left<A^{\ast}y^{\ast},x^{\ast\ast}\right>$.

Technically it will never be the case that $A=A^{\ast\ast}$ because literally $X\ne X^{\ast\ast},Y\ne Y^{\ast\ast}$. But when $Q:X\rightarrow X^{\ast\ast},Y\rightarrow Y^{\ast\ast}$ is surjective, where $\left<x^{\ast},Qx\right>=\left<x,x^{\ast}\right>$, then $X$ and $X^{\ast\ast}$, $Y$ and $Y^{\ast\ast}$ could be viewed as the same, and this is exactly when $X,Y$ are reflexive.

Hilbert space is reflexive because of the Riesz Representation Theorem.